# LDAP error during Rails5 System tests: Rack app error handling request { POST /login }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap, system-testing

The LDAP authentication is implemented in Rails using https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Authenticate-via-LDAP and it works fine.

An attempt to use LDAP during system tests http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing has failed:

```
Rack app error handling request { POST /login }
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
.../config/initializers/ldap_authenticatable.rb:92:in `ldap'
.../config/initializers/ldap_authenticatable.rb:60:in `bind_to_ldap'
.../config/initializers/ldap_authenticatable.rb:44:in `authenticate!'
```

The error occurs due to **ldap.yml** file, it seems the tests cannot read the configuration from the extern file. The workaround to replace the LDAP parameters

```
LDAP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml")[Rails.env]

def ldap
  ldap = Net::LDAP.new({
    :host => LDAP_CONFIG['host'],
    :port => LDAP_CONFIG['port'],
    ...
```

with

```
def ldap
  ldap = Net::LDAP.new({
    :host => 'ldap.domainname.com',
    :port => 636,
    ...
```

will avoid the error.

Please advise if this is a bug.

Comment: do you mind adding the content of your `/config/ldap.yml` file ?

Comment: here the content:

`development:
  host: "ldap.domainname.com"
  port: 636`

That's it! I realized the entry for **test** is missing. As soon as I added it, the test would read the yml file.

Comment: I see, so, you haven't defined those values for your test environment. `Rails.env` will be `test` when you run your specs/tests. So, what you need is to update that file and add the configuration for the test environment., Something like: `test: host: "ldap.domainname.com" port: 636`

Comment: yep, I've updated it and it worked, great! Thanks